# why Radio Button size() showing 0 in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, radio-button

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio");
List<WebElement> radio_buttons = driver.findElements(By.name("gender"));
System.out.println(radio_buttons.size());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those elements are inside `<iframe id="iframeResult" frameborder="0">`. You need to switch to `iframe` first:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("iframeResult")));

List<WebElement> radio_buttons = driver.findElements(By.name("gender"));
System.out.println(radio_buttons.size());
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! it works :-)